# How do I add an offset ot an IndexOf result in z3

Tags: z3, z3py

How do I add an offset to a value obtained from an `IndexOf` expression? That is, how do I do this?

```
> import z3
> s = 'hello'
> t = 'e'
> z3.simplify(z3.IndexOf(s, t, 0) + z3.IntVal(1))
z3.z3types.Z3Exception: Non-sequence passed as a sequence
```

I want to get the location after than of `e`.

On the other hand, switching the order works as expected

```
> z3.simplify(z3.IntVal(1) + z3.IndexOf(s, t, 0))
2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You found a bug in z3py!

The bug is on this line: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/python/z3/z3.py#L10150

which reads:

```py
    return SeqRef(Z3_mk_seq_index(s.ctx_ref(), s.as_ast(), substr.as_ast(), offset.as_ast()), s.ctx)
```

Instead, it should say:

```py
    return ArithRef(Z3_mk_seq_index(s.ctx_ref(), s.as_ast(), substr.as_ast(), offset.as_ast()), s.ctx)
```

I've reported this at their bug tracker: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/2159

Once you make that change in your local-copy of z3.py, your program should work as is. Or you can wait till they release a fix.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.

Comment: By the way, do you know how to invoke the doctests on z3's python API? I don't see any docs on it. If possible, I want to contribute a fix and a test to make sure this gets fixed fast.

Comment: I believe they have some sort of a builtbot that runs all the tests upon a commit. I don't know how to run it locally though. See here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3test